# What is better: Native query or JPA entities?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I was wondering about a question of concept. When accessing data in Spring Boot I see two ways. Creating SQL queries or using a relatively unspecific JPA/CRUD repository query and then filtering the result in java by accessing related entities via the entity object and lazy loading.

An example:

```
List<Car> unfilteredCars = carRepository.findAll();
List<Car> filteredByVendor = unfilteredCars.stream().filter( car -> car.getVendor().getId() == 3 ).toList()
```

I expect that an SQL query might be much more efficient, but testing of SQL queries is much more difficult and harder to maintain as well. I have queries with up to 5 joins which makes any update on the tables very painful. I am happy to sacrifice some efficiency for cleaner code and better maintainability.

What I am asking specifically is: Is the decrease in computing speed significant enough that I should stick with SQL statements or is it safe to use the java filtering approach for medium size applications?

Comment: Doing the filtering in your Java application is extremely inefficient (especially if you materialize the entire result in a `List`, instead of - for example - lazily using a `Stream` returned from the repository (but in that case, don't forget to close the stream(!))). This is in terms of memory, but also about the amount of data sent over the network, and the amount of work (CPU time) spent in encoding and decoding data, filtering, disk I/O on the database server, etc. However, a question like this is opinion-based and thus off-topic.

Comment: I think the approach you are taking in that example is not quite good. You should rely on the db engine to do the filtering instead of doing it in the code. For complex queries, it's complicated to maintain as you mentioned. In that case, I'd use a native query, for the simplest one, I'd use JPA repository

Comment: Why not use your Entities: JPQL for the queries too? Native SQL, I really don't understand the massive push in JPA forums with users using native queries when you have a query language based on your entities available that does the joins etc for you. This is simply "select car from Car car where car.vendor.id = :vendorId".

Comment: Okay thank you guys, that is just what I wanted to know